# Send dvt_curselkey values between 2 pages

Tags: 2010, filter

1. I have list (Plans of subdivisions) which I filter by several parameters (Division, year, quartal). 
   I do this through multiple dvwp connections. So there is a parameter `dvt.curselkey` for each dvwp, which contains the filter value. 
   I have the same filter data view web parts on the next page (Department, year, quartal) plus one new - Subdivision.

**Question**: how can I send these filters to the next page - the plan tasks of concrete subdivision - and apply these values to filter data there?

1. Plus I have a problem with setting a value for dvt.curselkey. For example I want to filter plans by current year not by first possible (2011). But when I tried to write initial value as '2012' year here `<xsl:param name="dvt_curselkey">##init##</xsl:param>` it didn't work.

   May be there is another solution to filter data in these lists..

PS: I want to do it without programming my own web parts in Visual Studio. I've already done this and I don't think it's right, if there is a way to do it through standard SP instruments.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: do it other way. I can send this values only using javascript and what I have achived is auto clicking on the item in dvwp which is connected with other dvwp so I can send initial filter parameter right from the moment the page loading. But I can't totally make it work (it doesn't stop clicking on this item with all possible conditions: was it item always clicked or not).

So, now I make this module through Visual Studio web part, i'll try to use only one page..

Wow! I can do it on one page even in spdesigner, making some blocks visible or not. I'll try it.